# Open hyperlink to image and import into PowerPoint

Tags: excel, image, vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

I have an Excel file with hyperlinks to web-based .jpeg files.  I would like to download these files and import them into a template in PowerPoint.

I have the following code to open a single hyperlink, but I have no idea how to go about managing the file as it is downloaded or how to transition to PowerPoint.

```
Range("K2").Select
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service.  You'll need to do some of the work yourself.

Note, though, that PPT can add images directly from a URL.  This snippet will add the image from the specified URL to slide 1, position it at upper left corner of the slide and make it its "natural" size ... whatever size PPT would normally insert it at if you did it manually:

```
Sub AddImageExample()
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        .Shapes.AddPicture "image_url_here", False, True, 0, 0, -1, -1
    End With
End Sub
```